# Error while using static variable

Tags: c, function, variables, static

I am learning C. Why doesn't the static variable increase above`1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo()
{
  static int a = 0;
  return a+1; 
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i = foo())
    printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Where is the mistake in this code ?

Comment: Why do you think it would?

Comment: @ColeJohnson then I didn't know that it doesn't make any sense. Now I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are not storing anything back into it. This should work for you:

```
int foo()
{
  static int a = 0;
  return ++a; 
}
```

Here `return  ++a` means `a = a + 1`, i.e., increment a first then return its value. `a+1` evaluates to `1` but does not store anything back into `a`

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning a value to the "a" variable. You are just returning the value of a+1 from your routine.

Answer (score 0):

The below will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo()
{
    static int a = 0;
    a++;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a infinite loop as you are returning a+1. every time it will return 0+1 and your a's value is not getting updating. as per you condition in you loop the loop runs infinity until the timeout occur. 
try this here a's value is keep on updating in every function call.

```
int foo()
{
    static int a = 0;
    a++;
    return a;
}
```